# "All the way back" vs "All the way in the back"

Tags: phrases, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning, sentence-meaning

Are "All the way back" vs "All the way in the back" the same ?

I found the explain for "All the way" phrase in here: https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/all-the-way

Do they depend on the context of the sentence?

For example, someone invite a friend to his exhibition. There is a picture that he want his friend to see it and he said: "It's all the way in the back.". Does he means the picture is in somewhere in the back of the exhibition or it's picture he put all the effort into doing it? If his mean is the second one, what is the role of the phrase "in the back" in this sentence? Does it emphasizes the phrase "all the way"?

Comment: "all the way in the back" is unusual / non-idiomatic. Something might be described as "way out back" to mean *at the rear of the building / property, **a long way from the "centre"***, and metaphoric "way back" is commonly used to mean *a long time ago*. In your context the speaker *probably* means the picture he's talking about has been placed ***well in the background*** at the exhibition (it's not being "promoted", perhaps because the artist isn't famous). Nothing to do with any effort he might have made painting it.

Comment: The example given by Macmillan - _We’ll have to go all the way back to get the list_ means 'We'll have to go back to where we came from", implying that that is a long way. As @FumbleFingers says, _all the way in the back_ is not a phrase you would expect to hear.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - “all the way in the back” sounds pretty idiomatic to me.  I’d take it to mean that to see this guys picture you have to make your way I  to the furthest point *(all the way)* away from the entrance *(in the back [of the room/hall/building])*.

Comment: “All the way in the back” refers to a location.  “All the way back” (in this context) is more about directions on how to get there.

Comment: ***all the way in the back*** is too many words for me to do an NGram search, but I'd have thought it would be vanishingly rare compared to ***right at the back***. Maybe the longer version is perfectly natural to you, but to me it would usually seem at least *slightly* "clunky".

Comment: thank you guys for your useful answers ^^